# Checking internet connection with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser, connectivity

Is there a way to check internet connection using pure JavaScript, without requesting something from the web? I've tried to use

```
alert(navigator.onLine);
```

but it always returns `true`.

Thanks!

Comment: The onLine preference only check if the browser is in offline mode or not. I think that you would have to perform a webrequest to find out if the computer is online or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you are trying to achieve this may be a lost cause. Having an Internet Connection 1 second does not mean you will have it the next (think mobile, spotty networks, dropped packets, tunnels, congested conference/airport wifi etc.)

You are better off to make an asynchronous request for the resource you want... if it works... Giddy Up!... if it fails, or times out, then deal with that scenario.

Answer (score 2):

please try the below code and update if it is working

```
function hostReachable() {


  var xhr = new ( window.ActiveXObject || XMLHttpRequest )( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" );
  var status;

  xhr.open( "HEAD", "//" + window.location.hostname + "/?rand=" + Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000), false );


  try {
    xhr.send();
    return ( xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300 || xhr.status === 304 );
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }

}
```

Comment: condition get failed. when Wifi is connection but internet is not working

Answer (score 0):

Please look follow link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine.onLine

Chrome Linux - Always returns true
Is it help you?

Answer (score 0):

`navigator.onLine` checks to see if you are online or offline, it returns true if you are online which is similar to saying that you have an active internet connection going on. it returns false if you are not online which is similar to saying you do not have an active internet connection

so you can do something like this below if your app needs to detect connection:

`if(navigator.onLine) { 
           //do something
}`

Comment: navigator.onLine is not dependable in Chrome and Safari. look it up on mozdev.